How to justify the way the ghost nodes are applied in Finite Difference Method?
Boundary problem consists of:

PDE which is fulfilled for the points inside some domain D, and
boundary conditions that apply to the points on the boundary.

In other words, the equation describes what happens inside the domain,
and it does not describe the solution on the boundary where the
boundary conditions are applied.
Now, I'm interested in grounds for using so-called ghost nodes
(1, 2).
which are commonly applied in finite difference schemes to enforce
Neumann boundary conditions and preserve better error bound
by using central difference rule both for domain and boundary points
(better when compared to forward or backward rule).
Let us consider 1D Laplace equation as an example:
\begin{eqnarray}
\nabla^2 u &= &0 \ for \ x \in (0,1) \\
u(0)  &=& a \\
u'(1) &=& b
\end{eqnarray}
Let us consider mesh given by $x_1=0, x_2, x_3, x_4=1$ equidistant points.
Algebraic form of the problem given above is:
\begin{eqnarray}
u_1  = a \\
u_1/h^2 - 2 u_2/h^2 +  u_3/h^2 = 0  \\
            u_2/h^2 - 2u_3/h^2 + u_4/h^2 = 0 \\
(u_5 - u_3)/(2h) = b
\end{eqnarray}
where $u_i = u(x_i)$ and $u_5$ is an auxiliary value in ghost node $x_5 = 1\frac{1}{3}$, which obviously lies outside the domain.
In order to get rid of $u_5$ the approach is as follows:
a) express $u_5$ with the use of boundary value:
\begin{eqnarray}
u_5  = u_3 + 2hb   \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)
\end{eqnarray}
b) apply it in PDE (i.e. enforce that PDE holds in $x_4$!):
\begin{equation}
  u_3/h^2 - 2u_4/h^2 + u_5/h^2 = 0    \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (2)
  \label{Eq2}
  \end{equation}
to get:
\begin{equation}
  u_3/h^2 - 2u_4/h^2 + (u_3 + 2hb)/h^2 = 0
  \end{equation}
and consequently
\begin{equation}
  2u_3/h^2 - 2u_4/h^2 = -2hb/h^2
\end{equation}
In this way we can construct solveable system of $n$ equations with
$n$ unknowns:
\begin{equation}
\begin{matrix}
u_1 &                &           &          &=& a \\
u_1/h^2 &- 2 u_2/h^2 &+  u_3/h^2 &           &=& 0  \\
         &   u_2/h^2 &- 2u_3/h^2 & + u_4/h^2 &= &0 \\
          &          &  2u_3/h^2 &- 2u_4/h^2 &= &-2hb/h^2
\end{matrix}
\end{equation}
However, haven't we just, in this very moment, assumed that
in boundary point $x_4$
both boundary condition (Eq. (1)) and the PDE (Eq. (2)) hold?
And isn't it inconsistent with the initial
assumption that on the boundary PDE only boundary condition holds,
and not the equation itself?
